# How can I allow hyphens in this RegEx

Tags: regex

I know a bit of RegEx but this one's a bit too complicated for me.
All I need to change is for it to allow for a single hyphen too.

```
replace(/[^\p{L}\s]+/gu, '')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
.replace(/^([^-]*-)|-/g, '$1').replace(/[^\p{L}\s-]+/gu, '')
```

It will keep the first `-` in the input string as well as any Unicode letters (`\p{L}`) and whitespaces (`\s`), because `.replace(/^([^-]*-)|-/g, '$1')` will match and *capture* - from the start of string - all chars other than `-` up to the first `-` (with `^([^-]*-)`) and then match any other `-` in the string and replace the matches with the value of Group 1 (it will be empty if the `-` is not the first hyphen in the string) and `.replace(/[^\p{L}\s-]+/gu, '')` will remove any one or more chars other than letters, whitespaces and hyphens (there will remain the first one only after the first replacement).

See the ECMAScript 2018+ JS demo below:

```js
console.log( "12-3-**(Виктор Викторович)**...".replace(/^([^-]*-)|-/g, '$1').replace(/[^\p{L}\s-]+/gu, '') )
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Wiktor! But I've just recognized an issue with that (for my implementation, not your code). I do want to prevent hyphens one after the other, but I still need to allow for more than 1 hyphen. I am using it to create tags just like SO, so I need to allow for something like `google-cloud-firestore` for example. Can you please show me how to alter that?

Comment: @Tsabary Sorry, I have too little details. "Something like" can be achieved with `text.replace(/(\p{L}-)|[^\p{L}\s]/gu, '$1')`.

Comment: Stribizew sorry for bringing the same one back, I thought it worked as I expected but just found out it's doesn't exactly.
So what I meant by my example, is that it should allow for more than just one hyphen, they just have t be between words (and not one after the other, or at the beginning). Currently, this only allows me to type one hyphen and when I try to type another after the second word then I am stuck. If you may, it would really help me to know how to allow for more than just one hyphen.

Comment: @Tsabary Then try `.replace(/^-+|(-){2,}/g, '$1').replace(/[^\p{L}\s-]+/gu, '')`

Comment: Amazing, thank you Wiktor, I really appreciate your help